# No voice response when running my project

Tags: python

I am making a personal assistant like jarvis using Python, but I'm having a problem on voice response. When I say the command, it replies, but only with text; there is no voice.

I am currently learning Python. Hope you can help me fix it thanks.

These are the requirements I use:

```
 certifi==2017.11.5
    chardet==3.0.4
    gTTS==1.2.2
    gTTS-token==1.1.1
    idna==2.6
    mpg123==0.4
    PyAudio==0.2.11
    pytz==2017.3
    SpeechRecognition==3.8.1
    urllib3==1.2
```

This is the code I use to run the project:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import webbrowser
import smtplib
import pyttsx3


def talkToMe(audio):
       print(audio)
       for line in audio.splitlines():
        os.system("say " + audio)


def myCommand():
        r = sr.Recognizer()

        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('waiting for your command sir')
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration = 1)
            audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            command = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
            print('You said: ' + command + '/n')

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print('Your last command couldn\'t be heard')
            command = myCommand();

        return command

def assistant(command):

        if 'hello' in command:
            talkToMe('Im here sir')



talkToMe('I am online and ready sir')

#loop to continue executing multiple commands
while True:
    assistant(myCommand())
```

Comment: when you call the `talkToMe()` function do you get any audio? Do you get any audio at all?

Comment: Not related to the question, but using `os.system()` runs substantial security risks. You'd be much safer to use `subprocess.call(['say', audio])` instead of `os.system('say ' + audio)`. Right now, if someone can get your system to try to "say" `$(rm -rf ~)`, you'll be having a very bad day.

Comment: Do you hear something when you enter the `say` line in your terminal?

Comment: @SPYBUG96 their is no audio also

Comment: Then that's not really a problem with your program. If you don't have a working `say` command, you need to fix that (and whatever your underlying OS-level issue is, be it volume set to silent or the wrong audio output driver being used or `say` not being a program that does text-to-speech at all).

Comment: @usr2564301 it say is not recognized as an internal or external command, operatable program or batch file

Comment: Ahh -- that means you don't **have** a `say` program installed at all. You can't run a program called `say` unless you *install* that program first.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the tip i guess i use the subprocess.call

Comment: That will not magically add `say` to your OS.

Comment: ... Although -- after trying -- it *will* result in a correct error message, so indeed better use that.

Comment: from the requirements shown above the latest versions are gTTS==2.0.1
 gTTS-token==1.1.2. so do pip install for the latest versions and then try.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one (if you are on a windows machine)

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

By the way I saw an extra space before the `line os.system("say " + audio)`.